# Laravel where clause based on conditions from value in database

Tags: sql, laravel

I am building an event reminder page where people can set a reminder for certain events. There is an option for the user to set the amount of time before they need to be notified. It is stored in `notification_time` and `notification_unit`. `notification_time` keeps track of the time before they want to be notified and `notification_unit` keeps track of the PHP date format in which they selected the time, eg. `i` for minutes, `H` for hours.

Eg.  `notification_time` - 2 and `notification_unit` - `H` means they need to be notified 2 hours before.

I have Cron jobs running in the background for handling the notification. This function is being hit once every minute.

```
Reminder::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('event_time', '>=', now()->subMinutes(Carbon::createFromFormat('i', 60)->diffInMinutes() - 1)->format('H:i:s'));
    $query->where('event_time', '<=', now()->subMinutes(Carbon::createFromFormat('i', 60)->diffInMinutes())->format('H:i:s'));
})
```

In this function, I am hard coding the `'i', 60` while it should be fetched from the database.  `event_time` is also part of the same table

The table looks something like this -

`id` `event_time` ... `notification_unit` `notification_time` `created_at` `updated_at`

Is there any way to solve this issue? Is it possible to do the same logic with SQL instead?

Comment: Any reason you can't just store a `notify_at` column, with the datetime of when they want to be notified? You could store that when the record is created, instead of storing time and unit. I think you're overcomplicating it. I don't know of a way to do it in SQL off the top of my head (I'm sure you can though), and the Laravel solution would involve loading all records, parsing the time, then filtering out ones that don't align, which is a pretty beefy function.

Comment: @TimLewis The need is much more complex than this, the reminder can be of once a year type which is repeating, so storing a particular date as `notify_at` is not at all logical. Loading all records is massive because the function runs every minute. Just imagine having a database with 10k+ records. Oh, also my case has 6 tables for the same thing.

Comment: That response makes sense :) I was simply asking if it was possible to use a static column instead of trying to programatically create it. Unfortunately, I still don't have an approach in mind, but I'll keep an eye on this question; it seems interesting

Comment: Your question is very interesting. I would try to mix things up. One table for the reminders with your actual configuration, another table for the notifications. This second table should have the `notify_at` pre-calculated. You probably will need a `sent` flag too. After every notification dispatch, you will need to insert the next notification with everything pre-calculated again. This way your cronjob will be very light-weight because you will only grab notifications for this minute. Don't forget to create an index for `dispatch_at` and `sent`.

Answer (score 0):

A direct answer to this question is not possible. I found 2 ways to resolve my issue.

#### First solution

---

Mysql has `DATEDIFF` and `DATE_SUB` to get timestamp difference and subtract certain intervals from a timestamp. In my case, the function runs every minute. To use them, I have to refactor my database to store the `time` and `unit` in seconds in the database. Then do the calculation. I chose not to use this way because both operations are a bit heavy on the server-side since I am running the function every minute.

#### Second Solution

---

This is the solution that I personally did in my case. Here I did the calculations while storing it in the database. Meaning? Let me explain. I created a new table `notification_settings` which is linked to the reminder (one-one relation). The table looks like this

`id`, `unit`, `time`, `notify_at`, `repeating`, `created_at`, `updated_at`

The `unit` and `time` columns are only used while displaying the reminder. What I did is, I calculated when to be notified in the `notify_at` column. So in the event scheduler, I need to check for the reminders at present (since I am running it every minute). The `repeating` column is there to keep track of whether the reminder is repeating or not. If it is repeating I re-calculate the `notify_at` column at the time of scheduling. Once the user is notified `notify_at` is set to null.